# react native 063 ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

Since I updated my project to 0.63 whenever i build for profiling the app errors on

```
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
```

When I run the app normally it works perfectly.

My pods has at the top...

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
```

I have even tried adding

```
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
```

To no avail.

I tried going to library search paths and removing

```
"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DoubleConversion"
```

But that didn't help either

I am running .xcworkspace project.

Any other ideas?

Comment: `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MusicApp-ckschnjmfsadgmbkyurbkxkwpcqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion'
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Im also facing the same error after upgradtion.
Any luck?

Comment: yes i was able to fix it ill add a answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so the answer was the the pods target was different to the projects target (this has always been like this and only appears to be an issue in RN 0.63.  So open the project in XCODE click on your project name and at the top it says ios deployment target

I also updated Xcode so it could also be that, i had an older version of XCODE because i downloaded it before it hit the store and then obviously didn't get updates